# How to filter a Cluster Map at run time

Tags: carto, cartocss, carto-js

I think I am a bit confused with CartoDB when doing maps at runtime.

Let's say I have a Cluster Map that includes all my data. However, I want to filter by a field. I thought one could simply set the new SQL (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE field = 'foo') to the sublayer,as it is done inside the platform, to select a subset and the visualization was to to be applied.

This does not appear to be the case, the SQL is a complex expression that includes all the calculation and has a lot of parameters making very difficult to reuse it.

Does anyone have a solution for this case? I dont think you *MUST* create a new visualization.

regards,

Answer (score 1):

If you want a ClusterMap at run time, you need to work with SQL **AND CartoCSS**.

For example, with CartoDB.js, you would need to copy and paste both (sql and cartocss) from Editor to CartoDB.js when you are setting the visualization.